# Linux Kernel: Ununderstood behaviour of read-write lock rwlock (Deadlock)

Tags: linux-kernel, synchronization, deadlock, rwlock

Experimenting with (linux kernel) rwlock API, and I'm getting a behavior (deadlock) that I cannot understand why it s happening.
Does someone have some explanation? (Please note the code is just for experiments no
logic behind: example I know that it is a bad idea to sleep while holding a spinlock but that
has no effect on the code I testing).

The Code is the following, and running results in a deadlock.

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>
#include <linux/kthread.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/spinlock.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("<toto@gmail.com>");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("test rwlock");
static DEFINE_RWLOCK(rwlock);

// shared variable
static int var;

static struct task_struct *w;
static struct task_struct *r1;
static struct task_struct *r2;

static int w_f(void *unsed)
{
    while (1) {
        printk("w: try to lock\n");
        if (write_trylock(&rwlock)) {
            printk("w: locked\n");
        } else {
            printk("w: unavailable lock, spin\n");
            write_lock(&rwlock);
            printk("w: out of spin\n");
        }

        var = 1;
        ssleep(4);
        write_unlock(&rwlock);
        printk("w: write unlock\n");
        if (kthread_should_stop()) {
            printk("w: should stop now\n");
            return 1;
        } else {
            printk("w: continue...\n");
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

static int r1_f(void *unsed)
{
    while (1) {
        if (read_trylock(&rwlock)) {
            printk("\tr1: locked\n");
            ssleep(3);
            printk("\tr1: read access\n");
            read_unlock(&rwlock);
        } else {
            printk("\tr1: unavailbe lock, spin\n");
            read_lock(&rwlock);
        }
        if (kthread_should_stop()) {
            printk("\tr1: should stop now\n");
            return 1;
        } else {
            printk("\tr1: continue...\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}


static int r2_f(void *unsed)
{
    while (1) {
        if (read_trylock(&rwlock)) {
            printk("\tr2: locked\n");
            ssleep(1);
            printk("\tr2: read access\n");
            read_unlock(&rwlock);

        } else {
            printk("\tr2: unavailbe lock, spin\n");
            read_lock(&rwlock);
        }

        if (kthread_should_stop()) {
            printk("\tr2: should stop now\n");
            return 1;
        } else {
            printk("\tr2: continue...\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


static int __init init_thread(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Thread creating ...\n");
    w = kthread_create(w_f, NULL, "writer1");
    r1 = kthread_create(r1_f, NULL, "reader1");
    r2 = kthread_create(r2_f, NULL, "reader2");
    if (w && r1 && r2) {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Thread Created Sucessfully\n");
        wake_up_process(w);
        wake_up_process(r1);
        wake_up_process(r2);
    } else {
        printk("Thread Creation Failed\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

static void __exit cleanup_thread(void)
{
    int ret, ret1, ret2;

    printk(KERN_ALERT "Cleaning up ...\n");
    ret = kthread_stop(w);
    ret1 = kthread_stop(r2);
    ret2 = kthread_stop(r2);
    printk("stop threads returned %d,%d,%d\n", ret, ret1, ret2);
}
module_init(init_thread)
module_exit(cleanup_thread)
```

I'm getting the log:

```
[0  291.18289] Thread creating ...
[0  291.18444] Thread Created Sucessfully
[0  291.18450] w: try to lock
[0  291.18453]  r1: locked
[0  291.18456]  r2: locked
[0  291.18459] w: unavailable lock, spin
[1  292.261093]     r2: read access
[1  292.261096]     r2: continue...
[1  292.261096]     r2: unavailbe lock, spin
[3  294.261151]     r1: read access
[3  294.261153]     r1: continue...
[3  294.261167] w: out of spin
[3  294.261168]     r1: unavailbe lock, spin
[7  298.265307] w: write unlock
[7  298.265308]     r1: continue...
[7  298.265308]     r2: continue...
[7  298.265309]     r1: locked
[7  298.265309]     r2: locked
[7  298.265314] w: continue...
[7  298.265314] w: try to lock
[7  298.265315] w: unavailable lock, spin
[8  299.269282]     r2: read access
[8  299.269285]     r2: continue...
[8  299.269286]     r2: unavailbe lock, spin
[10  301.269377]    r1: read access
[10  301.269380]    r1: continue...
[10  301.269381]    r1: unavailbe lock, spin
[33  324.122110] **NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#2 stuck for 22s! [writer1:3819]**
```

I tried to schematize the runtime:

```
(----) -> running(ssleep) holding the lock.
(====) -> spinning on the lock

time  0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     10    11    12         33
r1    *-----+-----+-----+=====+=====+=====+=====+-----+-----+-----+=====+=====+===== ... +=====+=====

r2    *-----+=====+=====+=====+=====+=====+=====+-----+=====+=====+=====+=====+===== ... +=====+=====

w     *=====+=====+=====+-----+-----+-----+-----+=====+=====+=====+=====+=====+===== ... +=====+=====
```

**The ununderstood behavior:**
I m wondering why (w) thread **keeps spinning at 10s**, the **situation is identical to instant 3s**: r2 is spinning, because w tried to acquire the write lock (w is spinning as r1 holds the lock), but when r1 is done, w should get unlocked and starts running. This happens at 3s but not at 10s.

Comment: Like with normal spinlock, the thread owning rwlock **should not sleep**, but you call `ssleep` function from it. Also, your `r2_f` function seems to miss unlock after `read_lock(&rwlock)`.

Comment: Running on:
Linux 4.4.0-138-generic #164-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 2 17:16:02 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

Yes fixed.

```
static int w_f(void *unsed)
{
    while (1) {
        printk("w: try to lock\n");
        if (write_trylock(&rwlock)) {
            printk("w: locked\n");
        } else {
            printk("w: unavailable lock, spin\n");
            write_lock(&rwlock);
            printk("w: out of spin\n");
        }

        var = 1;
        ssleep(4);
        write_unlock(&rwlock);
        printk("w: write unlock\n");
        if (kthread_should_stop()) {
            printk("w: should stop now\n");
            return 1;
        } else {
            printk("w: continue...\n");
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

static int r1_f(void *unsed)
{
    while (1) {
        if (read_trylock(&rwlock)) {
            printk("\tr1: locked\n");
        } else {
            printk("\tr1: unavailbe lock, spin\n");
            read_lock(&rwlock);
        }

        ssleep(3);
        printk("\tr1: read access\n");
        read_unlock(&rwlock);

        if (kthread_should_stop()) {
            printk("\tr1: should stop now\n");
            return 1;
        } else {
            printk("\tr1: continue...\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}


static int r2_f(void *unsed)
{
    while (1) {
        if (read_trylock(&rwlock)) {
            printk("\tr2: locked\n");
        } else {
            printk("\tr2: unavailbe lock, spin\n");
            read_lock(&rwlock);
        }
        ssleep(1);
        printk("\tr2: read access\n");
        read_unlock(&rwlock);

        if (kthread_should_stop()) {
            printk("\tr2: should stop now\n");
            return 1;
        } else {
            printk("\tr2: continue...\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


static int __init init_thread(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Thread creating ...\n");
    w = kthread_create(w_f, NULL, "writer1");
    r1 = kthread_create(r1_f, NULL, "reader1");
    r2 = kthread_create(r2_f, NULL, "reader2");
    if (w && r1 && r2) {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Thread Created Sucessfully\n");
        wake_up_process(w);
        wake_up_process(r1);
        wake_up_process(r2);
    } else {
        printk("Thread Creation Failed\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

static void __exit cleanup_thread(void)
{
    int ret, ret1, ret2;

    printk(KERN_ALERT "Cleaning up ...\n");
    ret = kthread_stop(w);
    ret1 = kthread_stop(r2);
    ret2 = kthread_stop(r2);
    printk("stop threads returned %d,%d,%d\n", ret, ret1, ret2);
}
module_init(init_thread)
module_exit(cleanup_thread)
```